# Solaris/OpenIndiana: Good documentation for permission-mechanism - roles, profiles and auths?

Tags: permissions, solaris

Are there any good documentation, HOWTOs or books (preferably free and online) describing the permission-mechanism for Solaris/OpenIndiana?  How `auths`, `profiles`, `roles`, `projects`, `groups` and `users` relate to each other... how to use the mechanism optimally... and what exactly the various named `auths`, `profiles` and `roles` actually are allowed to do, and what users should be assigned them and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joerg Moellenkamp's blog](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/) always has some nice insights. He wrote a little [PDF booklet](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/lksfbook/lksfbook_21022010.pdf) --"Less Known Solaris Features," which presents a narrative/examples on how to combine these features for use with least privilege and access control. Its all in the chapter on security.